# How to read all files in one folder and apply a function over them in python?

Tags: python, file, function, directory

I would like to run a function over all files in one folder and create new files out of them. I have put the code for one file bellow. I would appreciate it if you kindly help me.

```
def newfield2(infile,outfile):
    output = ["%s\t%s" %(item.strip(),2) for item in infile]
    outfile.write("\n".join(output))
    outfile.close()
    return outfile


infile = open("E:/SAGA/data/2006last/325125401.all","r")
outfile = open("E:/SAGA/data/2006last/325125401_edit.all","r")
```

I would like to change all the files in the 'E:/SAGA/data/2006last/' folder and create new files with edit extension.

Comment: Could you please fix the indent, I'm not sure whethere you have done it properly or not

Comment: sorry what do you mean by indent?

Comment: the number of spaces of each line from the left side

Comment: it works for each file but as the files are too much ,I need to do it automatically

Comment: @Wooble: *all files in one folder*. `os.listdir()` will do fine here.

Answer (score 4):

Use `os.listdir()` to list all files in a directory. The function returns just the filenames, not the full path. The [`os.path` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) gives you the tools to construct filenames as needed:

```
import os

folder = 'E:/SAGA/data/2006last'

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    infilename = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue

    base, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    infile = open(infilename, 'r')
    outfile = open(os.path.join(folder, '{}_edit.{}'.format(base, extension)), 'w')
    newfield2(infile, outfile)
```

Comment: outfile should be opened as 'w' mode.

Comment: thank you very much for your help.could you plz explain about the 'base and extension' and splitext ?

Comment: The `os.path.splitext()` function returns two values, the base filename without the extension, and the extension itself. The `base, extension = ` part makes Python assign those two values to the two separate variables, making it easier later on to construct a new filename.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def apply_to_all_files:
    for sub_path in os.listdir(path):
        next_path = os.path.join(path, sub_path)
        if os.path.isfile(next_path):
            infile = open(next_path,"r")
            outfile = open(next_path + '.out', "w")
            newfield2(infile, outfile)
```